# non primitive data types for modeling?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, migration, ado.net-entity-data-model

```
public class Song
    {
        public int SongID { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public virtual TagLib.Tag SongInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to use the "TagLib.Tag" data-type in my Song entity.
When I try to enable migrations I get:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'XmpNode' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_Exif_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_Exif_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'XmpTag_NodeTree_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_Xmp_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_Xmp_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_OtherTags_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_OtherTags_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_AllTags_Source' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: : The referenced EntitySet 'Tags' for End 'CombinedImageTag_AllTags_Target' could not be found in the containing EntityContainer.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'XmpNodes' is based on type 'XmpNode' that has no keys defined.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Tags' is based on type 'Tag' that has no keys defined.
```

How can I use external complex data-types in my model?

Comment: Please add Taglib.Tag class details

Answer (score 0):

I see that the error about Tag entity class that, you didn't define for this Key properties.

Perhaps your code is as follows:

```
public class Tag
{
    public string TagName{get; set;}
    // other fields
}
```

you must change it as follows:

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId{get; set;}
    public string TagName{get; set;}
    // other fields
}
```